# Cant turn on Wifi!

Tags: wireless

When i try to enable my wifi in linux os, the wifi automaticly disables. And i cant turn off the airplane mode. It says that the wifi is disabled and i have no idea to fix it. I was just writing code in VS code. Please help.

Comment: Try here: https://askubuntu.com/a/61547/20054

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to fn + f2
Oops
Sorry i found the answer